# What are options for implementing email or SMS from an embedded system?

Tags: embedded, smtp, sms

I'm interested in sending email notifications from a laboratory instrument (implemented on an ARM9, C/C++, RTOS). From what I understand, I would need to configure the SMTP gateway, username and password. The instrument has a limited UI, but I think we could manage it. Do solutions like this work? It seems like it would be convenient - but if the SMTP gateway is down - no email. It seems like there are similar solutions for SMS, but I'm wondering if I am putting to much complexity in the instrument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the RTOS you might have a look at [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/index.html) for a C++ solution, or possibly [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/home.html) if you're willing/able to use Lua.  I use LuaSocket in an embedded Linux device to send email and SMS, the SMS by looking up the phone's equivalent email address.

Comment: Thanks - Is it possible to lookup the cell phone carrier given a cell phone number? Or do you just ask the user to specify a carrier, as well as the phone number?

Comment: @Jeff - I ask for a phone number and a carrier.